# How make jQuery-DataTables responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, responsive-design

I have a question how to make the tables jQuery-DataTables responsive?

i already tried "responsive: true", but it's don't work

```js
    $(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable({
                "aaSorting": [[ 2, "asc" ]],
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sProcessing":   "Подождите...",
                    "sLengthMenu":   "Показать _MENU_",
                    "sZeroRecords":  "Записи отсутствуют.",
                    "sInfo":         "Показаны записи <b>_START_ - _END_</b> из <b>_TOTAL_</b>.",
                    "sInfoEmpty":    "",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "(Отфильтровано из _MAX_ записей)",
                    "sInfoPostFix":  "",
                    "sSearch":       "Поиск:",
                    "sUrl":          "",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst": "Первая",
                        "sPrevious": "«",
                        "sNext": "»",
                        "sLast": "Последняя"
                        }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://datatables.net/download/

This url will help you downloading everything about datatables and extensions. After downloading, you need to import .js and .css of the responsive extension into your `html` file.